# Use inner exceptions or create derived types of base exception

Tags: c#, exception

In cases where there is a method that calls many others and they can all throw a variety of exceptions from ArgumentExceptions to EndOfStreamExceptions, would it better to do a catch all and wrap it in your own exception and then set the inner exception, or create a base class exception and throw derived types. If throwing derived types that goes against the advice of reusing BCL exceptions where possible. So for example

```
public void A()
{
    if (someCondition)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException()
    }
}

public void B()
{
    if (anotherCondition)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperation()
    }
}

public void C()
{
    // Throws format exception
    int.Parse(x);
}

public void DoSomething()
{
    try
    {
        A();
        B();
        C();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw new DoSomethingException("Could not complete DoSomthing"){ InnerException = ex};
    }
}
```

OR would it be better do something like

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    A();
    B();
    C();
    D();
}

public void A()
{
    if (someCondition)
    {
        throw new DoSomethingMissingArg()
    }
}

public void B()
{
    if (anotherCondition)
    {
        throw new DoSomethingCannotStart()
    }
}

public void C()
{
    // Throws format exception
    if (!int.TryParse(x))
    {
        throw new DoSomethingFormatException("x must be in y format");
    }
}

public class DoSomethingException: Exception
{

}

public class DoSomethingMissingArg: DoSomethingException
{
    public DoSomethingMissingArg(){ }
}

public class DoSomethingCannotStart: DoSomethingException
{
    public DoSomethingCannotStart(){ }
}

public class DoSomethingFormatException: DoSomethingException
{
    public DoSomethingFormatException(){ }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That simply depends on whether your callers are likely to *need* that level of detail when catching your exceptions.

My suggestion would be to implement option 1 first, and then, if more details are required, switch to the following option 3:

```
public void A()
{
    if (someCondition)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException()
    }
}

...    

public void DoSomething()
{
    try
    {
        A();
    }
    catch(ArgumentException ex)
    {
        throw new DoSomethingMissingArgException() { InnerException = ex };
    }

    try
    {
        B();
        C();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw new DoSomethingException("Could not complete DoSomthing"){ InnerException = ex};
    }
}
```

Option 3 has the following advantages:

- It's backwards-compatible to option 1, since a DoSomethingMissingArgException *is a* DoSomethingException. And you can add more exception subclasses as needed *while staying backwards-compatible*.
- You have the DoSomething-specific exception logic only in method DoSomething, not scattered all around your helper methods, which can use the "natural" BCL execptions.